# how to do android sync

Tags: android, synchronization, amazon-s3, android-service, android-source

I am making app on android that take all data form device and Storage to amazon s3. but I am not sure how to do this.

same way take any new photo or video that will storage in same s3 account.

Comment: Dont know about amazon service, but if you have request/response structure then prepare your request/response string accordingly, made webservice call with this structure.

Comment: if possible then post link here, if possible only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS sdk for Android
[link](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/)